# Visual Studio TFS integration for Qt applications

Tags: qt, tfs, visual-studio-2013

We're developing a Qt application that needs to be built on both Linux and Windows hosts. On Linux we'll be using Qt Creator, and on Windows we'll use VS2013 with the Qt plug-in.

The workflow we're using in Visual Studio is to open the Qt .pro file, and allowing the VS plug-in to generate the solution and project files. If another developer makes changes to the project, I would get the latest source from TFS, then open the .pro file again, and allow the Qt plug-in to regenerate and overwrite the VS solution and projects. We're not storing the VS solution/project files in TFS.

The problem is that now we're not integrated with TFS. Modifying a file in one of the solution's projects does not automatically check out the file for editing. The solution for this is to bind the solution to to a project in TFS.

How does this work when the solution will be regenerated on a relatively frequent basis and probably break the binding? Do we have to rebind it every time?

It appears that trying to bind to source control fails, too. Of my solution and the two projects it contains, when I try to bind them to TFS only one of the projects says that its binding is valid. The solution and other project say "invalid", and of course don't give *any* information about why it's invalid. *It turns out that the solution and project files need to be in TFS for the binding to work.* Once I tried that i can bind them. (This doesn't explain why one of the three would properly bind...)

The real question here: **What is the recommended workflow for this scenario?**

---

Some additional information: Originally, the workflow was to have a set of .pro/.pri files for use with Qt Creator on Linux, and a set of .sln/.vcproj files for use on Windows. However, it appears some build-machine specific settings are included in the VS project files that cause builds to fail on different build machines. I read somewhere (can't find it now) that the preferred workflow is what I described up above the break.

Answer (score 0):

Using git would be a very natural way for crossplatfrom Qt project. :)
We do that and just happy with our source code repository.
There is some integration with Qt Wizard and another git utility called SourceTree (GUI). I believe VS2013 is fully capable of using git instead of TFS and there is kind of MS own way to do so. I used that for a short period of time.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/01/30/getting-started-with-git-in-visual-studio-and-team-foundation-service.aspx